# Camunda Engine - Execute custom code on new deployment

Tags: camunda

I'm working with the camunda engine on an JBoss server. I search a way to execute custom code if a new (version of) BPMN diagramm was deployed.

What I want:

1. Add/Upload new process
2. Run custom code automatically
3. Deploy new process by engine

Exists a listener or something like this that will executed if a new deployment was detected?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to use here is a "BPMN Parse Listener".

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/bpmn/parser/BpmnParseListener.java

Camunda provides a nice example of how to setup a parse listener here:

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/process-engine-plugin/bpmn-parse-listener

The original intent of Parse Handlers was to automatically add task or execution listeners to the process model. Why do you do this?
An example is if you automatically want all users to receive an email notification when they are assigned a task (a really common use case). Trouble is, modelling this into the process really messes up the process diagram. So...we use a ParseListener to inject the behavior automatically.

Now, how does this help your use case?

The answer is simple. It gives you access to the model deployment operation.
Every time a new model is deployed, the BPMN is "parsed" and any registered ParseListeners are triggered.

In your case, you would tie into the "parseProcess()" method and execute your custom code.

I would recommend you use a service call and externalize the custom logic so the call to the logic and the execution of the logic are abstracted, but that's up to you.

While an un-usual use case, this is actually a very nice use case for BpmnParseListeners.

Hope this helps.
Greg

Comment: This works for me. Thank you! I used the class `org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.AbstractBpmnParseListener`, this represent an empty implementation of the interface.